# How to get sharepoint list retention policy description

Tags: sharepoint

Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.InformationPolicy.ListPolicySettings API offers a method to set retention policy for a list:

```
public void SetRetentionSchedule(string retentionXml, string description)
```

There is GetRetentionSchedule method, which returns retentionXml. How to get back the description?

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If somebody looking for answer Lisa got this on msdn:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-BE/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/3a7323f6-a3fd-4e2b-9c67-27a1fc18c1c4

Answer (score 1):

This should sort you out: 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/3a7323f6-a3fd-4e2b-9c67-27a1fc18c1c4

Here's a powershell version:

```
function Get-RetentionScheduleDescriptionForFolder() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList]$List
    )
    $policyFile = $List.ParentWeb.GetFile(( Join-Uri list.RootFolder.Url "Forms/RetentionPolicy.Xml"));
    if ($null -ne $policyFile) {
        [xml]$xml = (New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString($policyFile.OpenBinary());
        $xml.RetentionItems.a.Desc;
    } 
}

function Join-Uri () {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$ChildPath )
    $scheme = (([System.Uri]$Path).Scheme)+'://'
    if($scheme -ne '://') {
        $joinedPath = Join-Path -Path $Path.Replace($scheme, '') -ChildPath $ChildPath
        $scheme+($joinedPath.Replace('\', '/'));
    } else {
        $joinedPath = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath $ChildPath
        $joinedPath.Replace('\', '/');
    }
}
```